# cypress stubbing with url with params

Tags: javascript, cypress

Was trying to stub my network request but I still can see the actual api been called in cypress. I did this cypress what went wrong?

```
describe("Test", () => {
    it("componentDidMount call", () => {
      cy.fixture("priceCheck").as("priceCheckData");
      cy.server();
      cy.route(
        "GET",
        "https://staging.gobear.co/price?rate_id=*&gobear_item_id=123",
        "@priceCheckData"
      );

      cy.visit(
        "http://localhost:6006"
      );

    });
  });
```

I think it's something wrong with the wildcard in the route url. I tried an exact match url like this

```
 cy.route(
      "GET",
      " http://www.mocky.io/v2/5eba1e742f000066953c3520",
      "@priceCheckData"
    );
```

It's working